# Not able to pass parcelable object ArrayList to a fragment activity

Tags: android, fragment, parcelable

I have a Activity A which has a ArrayList of object which i parceable..
Object is :

```
    public class DashBoardPOJO implements Parcelable {

private String dashBoardName;
private String dashBoardId;
private String dashBoardStatus;
private ArrayList<DashBoardDataPOJO> dashBoardDataList;
private boolean loaded;

public ArrayList<DashBoardDataPOJO> getDashBoardDataList() {
    return dashBoardDataList;
}

public void setDashBoardDataList(
        ArrayList<DashBoardDataPOJO> dashBoardDataList) {
    this.dashBoardDataList = dashBoardDataList;
}

public boolean isLoaded() {
    return loaded;
}

public void setLoaded(boolean loaded) {
    this.loaded = loaded;
}

public String getDashBoardStatus() {
    return dashBoardStatus;
}

public void setDashBoardStatus(String dashBoardStatus) {
    this.dashBoardStatus = dashBoardStatus;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(dashBoardName);
    dest.writeString(dashBoardId);
    dest.writeList(dashBoardDataList);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<DashBoardPOJO> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DashBoardPOJO>() {
    public DashBoardPOJO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DashBoardPOJO(in);
    }

    public DashBoardPOJO[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DashBoardPOJO[size];
    }
};

public DashBoardPOJO() {

    dashBoardName = null;
    dashBoardId = null;
    dashBoardDataList = null;
    /*
     * userName=null; userId=null;
     */

}

private DashBoardPOJO(Parcel in) {

    dashBoardName = in.readString();
    dashBoardId = in.readString();
    in.readList(dashBoardDataList, null);

}

// GETTERS AND SETTERS............

public String getDashBoardName() {
    return dashBoardName;
}

public void setDashBoardName(String dashBoardName) {
    this.dashBoardName = dashBoardName;
}



public String getDashBoardId() {
    return dashBoardId;
}

public void setDashBoardId(String dashBoardId) {
    this.dashBoardId = dashBoardId;
}
```

}

I want to pass the ArrayList to a activity which extends Fragment Activity.

I am sending the object like this

```
                                                       Intent intent = new Intent(
                                                            DashboardActivity.this,
                                     BaseFragmentActivity.class);

                                                     intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("dashBoardList", dashBoardList);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
```

And receiving it at the fragment activity like this

```
        dashboardList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("dashBoardList");
```

But still the intent is returninig me a null value... Pls help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private DashBoardPOJO(Parcel in) {
    dashBoardName = in.readString();
    dashBoardId = in.readString();
    dashBoardDataList = (ArrayList<DashBoardDataPOJO>) in.readArrayList(DashBoardDataPOJO.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

Comment: getting error...cannot cast void to arraylist<DashBoardDataPOJO>

Comment: @user1901079 Sorry, my mistake. I edited the answer, please try now